# Why the process is getting killed at 4GB?

Tags: linux, process, 64-bit

I have written a program which works on huge set of data. My CPU and OS(Ubuntu) both are 64 bit and I have got 4GB of RAM. Using "top" (%Mem field), I saw that the process's memory consumption went up to around 87% i.e 3.4+ GB and then it got killed.

I then checked how much memory a process can access using "uname -m" which comes out to be "unlimited".

Now, since both the OS and CPU are 64 bit and also there exists a swap partition, the OS should have used the virtual memory i.e [ >3.4GB + yGB from swap space ] in total and only if the process required more memory, it should have been killed.

So, I have following ques:

1. How much physical memory can a process access theoretically on 64 bit m/c. My answer is 2^48 bytes.
2. If less than 2^48 bytes of physical memory exists, then OS should use virtual memory, correct?
3. If ans to above ques is YES, then OS should have used SWAP space as well, why did it kill the process w/o even using it. I dont think we have to use some specific system calls which coding our program to make this happen.

Please suggest.

Comment: 2^48 bytes is the total addressable space, a process cannot use it all -- the kernel address space must also fit in that. Is it killed by the OOM killer?

Comment: Is the app compiled 64bit? A 32bit app on a 64bit system is still subject to the 4gig memory limit.

Comment: Also, how do you allocate? mmap, malloc, shm, other, all?

Comment: @fge: yes, it is being killed by OOM. I checked it from the kernel logs.

Comment: @MarcB: Yes, it is 64 bit executable.

Comment: @fge: I am basically using two data structures, Vector and Hash. I have not used C++ hashmap but implemented it myself. There I am allocating using new. But, I am sure hash is not the problem bcoz that will not grow beyond 400 MB. It is the vector (of type string) which is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `file` and `ldd` that your executable is indeed 64 bits.

Check also the resource limits. From inside the process, you could use [getrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) system call (and `setrlimit` to change them, when possible). From a `bash` shell, try `ulimit -a`. From a `zsh` shell try `limit`.

Check also that your process indeed eats the memory you believe it does consume. If its pid is 1234 you could try `pmap 1234`. From inside the process you could read the `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/1234/maps` (which you can read from a terminal). There is also the `/proc/self/smaps` or `/proc/1234/smaps` and `/proc/self/status`  or `/proc/1234/status` and other files inside your `/proc/self/` ...

Check with  `free` that you got the memory (and the swap space) you believe. You can add some temporary swap space with `swapon /tmp/someswapfile` (and use `mkswap` to initialize it).

I was routinely able, a few months (and a couple of years) ago, to run a 7Gb process (a huge `cc1` compilation), under Gnu/Linux/Debian/Sid/AMD64, on a machine with 8Gb RAM.

And you could try with a tiny test program, which e.g. allocates with `malloc` several memory chunks of e.g. 32Mb each. Don't forget to write some bytes inside (at least at each megabyte).

standard C++ containers like `std::map` or `std::vector` are rumored to consume more memory than what we usually think.

Buy more RAM if needed. It is quite cheap these days.

Comment: I actually suspect (and I was already told) that `std::vector` has significant overhead. I can't be more specific, because I did not dive into libstdc++ source code (it is inside GCC).

Comment: - As I already mentioned, memory limit shown by uname is "unlimited". Is there something else you want me to check?

- Your suggestion regarding pmap and /prov/self/* is good. I will try that.

- I can also try using swapon. But that is also one of my questions, why OS itself it not taking care of it using virtual memory. What is it that a programmer need to worry about it?

- In your case, it quite makes sense bcoz u had 8GB and the process required 7GB. My case is just the opposite.

- Not sure how malloc will help me out when I already have a program which is dying at 4GB

Comment: - STLs using more memory can be a case. This is a good point to consider.


- Buying RAM is definitely an option. But the point of this question was to figure out that "something" not known to me or to say how to extract the max out of my HW :)

Comment: STLs may be an overhead. But the point is why OS is not using the swap space.

Comment: Long time ago (perhaps 8 or 10 years ago) I had a 32 bits x86 Linux machine, and I remembered having run a process (SML/NJ compilation) which ate twice the available RAM [perhaps 0.5 or 1Gb] by going to swap. It ran very slowly (1% of CPU, the rest being waiting for disk for swap).

Comment: Are you sure that swap space is enabled? Check with `free` !

Answer (score 2):

It's not only the data size that could be the reason. For example, do `ulimit -a` and check the max stack size. Have you got a kill reason? Set 'ulimit -c 20000' to get a core file, it shows you the reason when you examine it with gdb.

Comment: Hmm, this can be helpful. Actually, I am using a vector<string> which is a local variable. And this vector contains huge amount of data. But still, being a STL, I thought its memory needs must be fulfilled using heap and not stack. And if that is the case, the max stack segment size wont matter. What do you suggest?

Comment: @ott-- OOM killer, see question comments. Tuning it is a PITA :/

Comment: There are links to some articles at the end of page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory how to deal with oom killer.

Answer (score 0):

In what can be addressed literally EVERYTHING has to fit into it, including your graphics adaptors, OS kernel, BIOS, etc. and the amount that can be addressed can't be extended by SWAP either.

Also worth noting that the process itself needs to be 64-bit also. And some operating systems may become unstable and therefore kill the process if you're using excessive RAM with it.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. And the process is also 64 bit.