# Python gets killed without reaching the memory limit

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have simple script that tries to add images to a dictionary. It seems that it is killed due to memory issue.

```
import numpy as np
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    test_dict = {}
    
    for i in range(150):
        print(i)
        img = np.ones((5000, 5000))
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
        test_dict[i] = img
```

The result is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
Killed
```

I understand that the memory is increasing as I keep adding items to the dict. So I plot the memory usage for this script

[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jmKC.png)

It shows that it uses less than 4G.

I am wondering why this is an issue.

I checked the system memory by `free -h` and got

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            59G        3.2G         40G        203M         16G         56G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

The script is far from reaching the memory limit.
I also check by `ulimit` and don't see a memory limit for python.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694607/why-the-process-is-getting-killed-at-4gb

Comment: @RandomDavis My question was, why 4G is the limit for my script. It seems that the available memory got from "free -h" is way more than 4G?

Comment: This comment from the link shared by @RandomDavis may be relevant -- "Is the app compiled 64bit? A 32bit app on a 64bit system is still subject to the 4gig memory limit."

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks for the suggestion. I checked that the python and the system are both 64 bit. Not sure what else I can test?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Sorry for this dumb comment as I am pretty new to this area. It is running in some docker container. I am guessing the docker container may have a limit for memory consumption?